# How can I specify format in the Phoenix.ConnTest?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ex-unit

I have a pretty simple code in the phoenix controller. It does some stuff and returns content depending on the format:

```
def delete(conn, _params) do
  # some stuff here

  if get_format(conn) == "json" do
    conn |> put_status(200) |> json(%{})
  else
    conn |> redirect(to: "/")
  end
end
```

It works properly, but I have a problem with testing it. I can't test html return. How can I do it? [dispatch/5](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.ConnTest.html#dispatch/5) doesn't have anything related to format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format is defined via `accept` header for connection, not for `get` or whatever. For json & html formats it should be `application/json` or `html/text`, respectively.

You can use this `conn` in your tests:

```
conn = build_conn
  |> Plug.Conn.put_req_header("accept", "text/html")
```

Comment: When one says “test,” readers are usually expect `assert` and/or `doctest`, or any other _test_, rather than simple assignment that just works always.